# react: how to display array data through map group by using date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to display data in a table. My problem is that date is coming with all the rows. date is same for every item. How to display date and FeatureName(same value) once in the table header for all the items.

```
{"FeatureID":"11","FeatureText":Feature2,"Date":"08/30/2011","FeatureName":"Research"},
{"FeatureID":"12","FeatureText":Feature3,"Date":"08/30/2011","FeatureName":"Research"},
{"FeatureID":"13","FeatureText":Feature4,"Date":"08/30/2011","FeatureName":"Research"}]
```

```
import React from "react";
export class DisplayFeatures extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
              FeatureID: "",
              Date: "",
              FeatureName
              FeatureText: "",
              Feature: [],
       }
}
       componentDidMount() {
              this.DisplayFeatures();
}
DisplayFeatures() {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                            this.setState({
                                  Feature: data,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
      }
       render() {
              return (
                     <div>
                           <form>
<table><tbody>
{this.state.Feature.map((item, index) => {
       return [
              <div>
                    <tr><td>
                           <font size="4" color="#FFFFFF"><b>{item.FeatureName}</b></font></td>
                           <td>
                           {item.date}</td></tr>
                          <td>{item.FeatureText}</td></tr></div>
       ];

})}</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
              );
       }
}
export default DisplayFeatures;
```

Comment: For the table header, you can simply do   `<th> Feature: {this.state.Feature[0].FeatureName} Date: {this.state.Feature[0].date}</th>`  outside of the `map` function. You can also keep a seperate state object for                    
   `FeatureName` and  `date`  when you update state after fetch using the same technique.

Comment: This solution is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like lodash to group by date first, then render the list.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-groupby-method/

```
    import React from "react";
export class DisplayFeatures extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
              FeatureID: "",
              Date: "",
              FeatureName: "",
              FeatureText: "",
              Feature: [],
              FeatureGroupedByDate: [],
       }
}
       componentDidMount() {
              this.DisplayFeatures();
}
DisplayFeatures() {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                            this.setState({
                                  FeatureGroupedByDate: _.groupBy(data, item => item.Date),
                                  Feature: data,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
      }
```

You can also select the first item from the array to use as the header

Comment: We cannot use any third party library. Please suggest another solution in react.

Comment: @TestUser Did you check my comment on your post?

Comment: How to do if we need to group be one more field FeatureName. Also how array may needs to be modified while displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this code

```
import React from "react";
export class DisplayFeatures extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
           FeatureID: "",
           Date: "",
           FeatureName: "",
           FeatureText: "",
           Feature: [],
           FeatureGroupedByDate: [],
       }
}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.DisplayFeatures();
  }
DisplayFeatures() {
     fetch(REQUEST_URL)
          .then(response => response.json())
           .then((data) => {
                 this.setState({
                 FeatureGroupedByDate: data.reduce(function(rv, x) {
                       (rv[x['Date']] = rv[x['Date']] || []).push(x);
                          return rv;
                 }, {}),
                 Feature: data,
                 loading: false
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: How to do for two fields, if we need to group by date as well as FeatureName

Answer (score 0):

> **Changes made:**
>
> 1. Added initial `loading` state.
> 2. Changed `Feature` state to `Features`. (Plural, because it holds multiple feature data).
> 3. Created seperate state for `FeatureName` and `FeatureDate`
> 4. updating the `FeatureName` and `FeatureDate` during `setSate` call  in the
>    constructor.
> 5. Added loading state check in `render` function. (upto you to use a better loading animation.)

```
import React from "react";

export class DisplayFeatures extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          FeatureDate: "",
          FeatureName: "",
          Features: [],
          loading: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.DisplayFeatures();
    }

    DisplayFeatures() {
      setTimeout((()=> {
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              this.setState({
                Features: data,
                FeatureName: data[0].FeatureName,
                FeatureDate: data[0].date,
                loading: false
              });
            });
      }, 5000);
    }

    render() {

        if(this.state.loading){
            return <div>Loading... </div>
        }else{
            return (
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <table>
                            <th> Feature: {this.state.FeatureName} Date: {this.state.FeatureDate}</th>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.Features.map((item, index) => {
                                    return 
                                    <>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> 
                                                <font size="4" color="#FFFFFF"><b>{item.FeatureName}</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                            
                                            <td>
                                                {item.date}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{item.FeatureText}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </>
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
export default DisplayFeatures;
```

Comment: Thanks John for all the help. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: On page refresh, it gives error unhandled rejection, cannot read properties of undefined (reading FeatureName)

Comment: @TestUser Can you please check it again? I added the `loading state check` in `render` function.

Comment: Error is still there. As soon as page refresh, it gives error unhandled rejection, cannot read properties of undefined (reading FeatureName) . Does it need to be saved in localstorage?

Comment: I am looking into it. Please wait, let me check why that's happening.

Comment: Bro there's seems to be no problem. I simulated fetch using setTimeout o 5 seconds and it works. [code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-voice-5h4qto?file=/src/DisplayFeatures.js)

Comment: this is my code. first time it wors perfectly. on page refresh data[0].FeatureName looks like its empty. If i harcode the values, its erfectly fine. DisplayFeatures() {
             fetch(REQUEST_URL) .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                 Feature: data,
                                 FeatureName: data[0].FeatureName,
                                 Date: data[0].Date,  loading: false
                           })
                    })
       }

Comment: seems like a problem with your api response. Please console log the response and check the reponse actually have featureName property after refresh.

Comment: i added setTimeout for fetch. test it out and see if it helps, or please check your api response as i mentioned. This thread is getting too long so, I will end it here.